# Java jxl api on Linux using terminal (no IDE)

Tags: java, linux, classpath, javac

I need to compile a small Java program (that runs OK on Eclipse) but using the terminal interface on a Linux (Fedora) OS. I have downloaded the jexcelapi jar file and extracted it in the same directory where I have the Java JDK.
I try to compile using :

```
javac -cp <paths> filename.java
```

and I get the errors

```
"error: cannot find symbol RowsExceededException, WriteException, IOException, BiffException".
```

The source file has

```
import jxl.*;
```

The location of jexcelapi directory is:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_06/jexcelapi
```

jexcelapi contains directories:

`build`, `docs`, `resources`, `src`, and file `jxl.jar`

Obviously I have `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_06/jexcelapi` in the `-cp <paths>`

Please help

Fab

Answer (score 2):

For the future, to find out what's on classpath and what is not, you could try to run with the `-verbose` option.

```
javac -verbose -cp <paths> filename.java
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the jar file not the directory in the classpath:

```
javac -cp .:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_06/jexcelapi/jxl.jar filename.java
```